# Dragula: How to drag a container into a container?

Tags: dragula

I am using Dragula and I love it. But recently I came upon a problem that I cannot solve, hence I need your kind help.

I have files, folders and a trashcan. I would like to enable that files can be dragged to folders and the trashcan, but at the same time, I would like to enable dragging a folder to the trashcan.

This makes a folder both a container and a dragable element, and this appear not to be possible.

I sincerely hope I am missing something, please tell me what it is...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After another day of work I realized, that I can actually just instantiate another dragula, so now I have 2. One is handling drag and drop of files and another is handling dragging of folders. I love this library :-)